# Client side optimization issue

Tags: jquery, performance, client-side

Consider the following casses.

1. Multiple `js` files are `compressed/gzipped` and placed in a one file which is in the head section of the HTML document.
2. The compressed file(containing few files) is located in the footer section(when the DOM is built).

Is it true that placing `compressed/gzipped` javascript in script tags at the footer gives small performance boost?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Moving them down will help.
And you can do this as well call another script file from one single script. So With only 1 HTTP request you will fetch all JS files parallely.
http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/posts/2007/07/high_performanc_5/

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html

Answer (score 0):

Keep an eye on script-loaders, which are another way of improving performance. The guiding principle is to allow you to load scripts in a non-blocking and organized way (including load order and conditional loading), which while using more HTTP requests allows them to load in parallel for speedier response.

The most popular of these is [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/) but I also rather like [head.js](http://headjs.com/) which can do double-duty with some Modernizr-type stuff.

If that's not enough to convince you, you can still specify order of execution (ensuring dependencies are met) and fire off callbacks.

Every tool should be chosen for its suitability, though. In many cases, the "move to the bottom of the page" technique is absolutely appropriate. You shouldn't use a module/script loader "just because you can".